# Argument type MouseEvent is not assignable to parameter type MouseEvent

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea

[image]

In Intellij v. 2018.3.2. I'm getting this error every time I pass the `$event` to a method.

In template I have:

```
<a href="#" (click)="toggle($event)">{{ header }}</a>
```

Then in class:

```
public toggle(event: MouseEvent): void {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's a bug in the IDE. I've submitted a ticket for it: [youtrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36778).